# Token remember me for flask-login saved in the database?

Tags: python, cryptography, flask, flask-login

So usually in large websites I work with, you want to save some session information to the database, so that cookies can't be easily duplicated.

Using flask-login there is a way to use token_loader, to implement a function to query a Session table for example, for mapping the token to the id.

But this means that the session table will be the same size as the user table.

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
token = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True)
uid = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)


@login_manager.token_loader
def token_load(token):
    return User.sessions.first().token
```

I've seen sites with 8 MB full of user table information. Sites gets clogged up with session table rows in Drupal for example. Is it wise to store tokens in this way? Just a row for each user telling us their token value?

Basically it's like a password table for identifying users who have cookies instead of actually logging in.

Anyone seen an implementation of this anywhere in flask-login?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question, but if it is about saving token information for the user then well... You can save the token to the same users table, where you have already the ID of it. It will be just one additional field. Or could be user profile table, or... then yes, the separate table with mappings (if you want to separate users table from this data, because of some kind of security, then you don't have any other choice I guess). If I misunderstood the question - sorry :)

Comment: Yes, I'm just asking for the best way to do this. I mean I am not even sure if this is 100% security if all we are doing is adding a hash to a cookie and checking to see if the hash matches a user. In essence, once a hacker gets your hash, he can log in as you (so is it much of a security?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just go with the additional field in the Users table. This will avoid data to be duplicated in another table. I don't see any point to have separate table if you will save only ID and token there. But if you plan to add some more information to it (like time when the token was created, some other stuff to be more secure and validate the token later, ip address from the the token was generated or smth else), then of course you will need separate table. My 2c :)

Comment: But do things like ip / token validation, really improve security?

Comment: I would say yes, if your token is for short term (minutes, hours). But if you want the user to be logged in automatically after few days, then IP address doesn't make sense, only the hash in the cookie then could be helpful. What I think would be worth to store anyway is the time when you issued the token for the user. I think it is worth to have possibility to require re-login if for example token is 2 months old... or if user never used the token for a month. Anyway if the cookie gets stolen - end of the security story :D

Comment: Yeah this was my concern. I mean the whole point of remember_me cookie is to remember the user for 365 days. If that's the case, then what is the threat? 1. they steal your cookie, then no matter what you put in it, it's not secure. 2. they replicate the cookie you have, but if you hash it, then it can't be replicated. 3. they sniff your cookie over wifi, in that case you need to decrypt the cookie and IP check the cookie, but then the user has to relogin every IP change. (this is probably why banks never login people via cookies).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be overcomplicating things. If you want to use sessions stored on server side and not in cookies, you can also use something like redis to store the session. All you have to do is write your own session inteface using example such as below:

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/

Now, if you want to use "remember me" for 365 days, then just do this in your flask app

```
from datetime import timedelta
app.secret_key = 'some secret random string'
session.permanent = True
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=365)
```

Comment: I think using a new concept like redis is overcomplicating this. Look at the size of that code snippet. I don't even think you have to make the session permanent, a cookie is being used by flask-login to already accomplish this task.